# Longtabu table with over 10000 rows inserts a } and then throws an error

Tags: tabu

this table below encopasses a file that will have > 1 rows in it. When the number of rows = 10000 then the 
following message is shown in the out put and causes the compilation to fail. any ideas how not to get the } to be inserted?

```
   ! Missing } inserted.
    <inserted text>
    }
    l.10001 0
    6-Jun-2014 & Chq - \#9113 & 60.60 &  & 3,564,175.18 \\
    ! Argument of \LT@max@sel has an extra }.
    <inserted text>




\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}



\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[top=0.4in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in, tmargin = 0.9in] {geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



 % define lightgray
 \definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
 \definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.5}
 \definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,63,55}

\let\oldlongtabu\longtabu
\let\endoldlongtabu\endlongtabu

\newenvironment{newlongtabu}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}
   \oldlongtabu} {\endlongtabu}

\renewenvironment{longtabu}{
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}
    \oldlongtabu} {\endoldlongtabu}

\begin{document}

\newdimen\mylength
\setlength{\mylength}{7.0in}
{\small \tabulinesep=1.2mm
 \begin{longtabu}to\textwidth{Xp{10.0cm}rrr}
    \rowcolor{lightgray} 
     \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & ~ &  ~ &  col5 \\
    \rowcolor{white}\\
   \endfirsthead
   \rowcolor{lightgray}
   \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & ~ &  ~ &  co5 \\
   \rowcolor{white}\\
    \endhead
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
      \input blah_short.tex
  \end{longtabu}
  }
  \end{document}
```

the blah_short contains:

```
blah  & blah & blah  & blah & blah \\
blah  & blah & blah  & blah & blah \\
blah  & blah & blah  & blah & blah \\
blah  & blah & blah  & blah & blah \\
blah  & blah & blah  & blah & blah \\
blah  & blah & blah  & blah & blah \\
```

a regular one would have the row count over 10000.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should at least tell us what's in rows 9999, 10000, and 10001 of `details.tex`...

Comment: it would also be useful to know what document class you are using, and any other packages that may interact with construction of the table.  you might try editing  (a copy of) the file so that the table has exactly 9999 rows and see if processing completes "normally".  it sounds like some counter is overflowing, but i haven't the foggiest idea of where to look without more clues.

Comment: once 9999 is hit the processing compiles as wanted.

Comment: I've added a MWE now. Sorry for the confusion before.

Comment: it's kind of interesting that 10000 is equal to `\@M` = "infinity" in tex terms.  perhaps a place to start looking.

Comment: OK this was promising by altering the \@M to @MM in the tabu package this fixed the problem, but is there any way to redefine the @M variable within my code?

Comment: if I try with 11001 rows I get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. rather than the error you show?
`

Comment: This is due to a limitation with latex compiler that you are using. I've had previous internal memory limitations with PDFlatex. switching to lualatex was the fix for the memory issue.

Comment: @hwq -- even though switching to `longtable` solves the problem, it seems that you have uncovered a limitation; i've just done a quick scan of the manual (`texdoc tabu`), and that limitation isn't documented -- and i think it should be.  other people might be helped if you would report this to the author of the `tabu` package, providing the problem example and letting him know what you changed to make it work.

Comment: @barbara-beeton It looks like the authors know of it. Based of of this link [http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf] the relevant passage is on page 25.

Comment: @hwq -- thanks for that.  i looked at it, but didn't realize the significance, since i'm not a `tabu` user and not familiar with its component names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I extend your input file to 11001 identical rows tabu gives out of memory errors

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. rather than the error you show?

the underlying longtable code is designed to cope with essentially arbitrary length tables  (up to document lengths imposed by pdftex and the pdf format)

something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{longtable}




\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[top=0.4in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in, tmargin = 0.9in] {geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



 % define lightgray
 \definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
 \definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.5}
 \definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,63,55}


\begin{document}

\newdimen\mylength
\setlength{\mylength}{7.0in}
{\small 
 \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}p{10.0cm}rrr}
    \rowcolor{lightgray} 
     \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & ~ &  ~ &  col5 \\
    \rowcolor{white}\\
   \endfirsthead
   \rowcolor{lightgray}
   \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & ~ &  ~ &  co5 \\
   \rowcolor{white}\\
    \endhead
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
      \input blah_short.tex
  \end{longtable}
  }
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Changing the longtabu to longtable worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If a `longtabu` is needed then you can give a large data set the space to work by overriding the `LTChunkSize` counter while making the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}



\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[top=0.4in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in, tmargin = 0.9in] {geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



 % define lightgray
 \definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
 \definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.5}
 \definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,63,55}

\let\oldlongtabu\longtabu
\let\endoldlongtabu\endlongtabu

\newenvironment{newlongtabu}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}
   \oldlongtabu} {\endlongtabu}

\renewenvironment{longtabu}{
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}
    \oldlongtabu} {\endoldlongtabu}

\begin{document}

\newdimen\mylength
\setlength{\mylength}{7.0in}
{\small \tabulinesep=1.2mm
 \begin{longtabu}to\textwidth{Xp{10.0cm}rrr}
    \rowcolor{lightgray} 
     \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & ~ &  ~ &  col5 \\
    \rowcolor{white}\\
   \endfirsthead
   \rowcolor{lightgray}
   \textbf{col1} & \textbf{col2} & ~ &  ~ &  co5 \\
   \rowcolor{white}\\
    \endhead
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
      \setcounter{LTchunksize}{250000}
      \input blah_short.tex
  \end{longtabu}
  }
  \end{document}
```

the  `\setcounter{LTchunksize}{250000}` will allow you a table size of 250000 records. Combine this with a 200000 line input file, and lualatex you are also looking at 1.2 GB memory footprint for a couple of minutes as it compiles.